# Is there a way to exclude specific branch names/patterns in GitHub branch protection?

Tags: github

I want to enable GitHub branch protection on all branches *except* those prefixed with "private_", for example. This way, we do not have to enable every new 'non private' branch as it is created.

I cannot find a way, using GitHub's pattern matching/globbing rules, to accomplish this. Something like a "/^private*/" rule would be ideal.  Unfortunately, we do not enforce naming conventions, so a "*common-prefix**" rule wouldn't help here.

Does anyone know of a way to do this, in the GUI branch protection rules, not via the API?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Using `**\**` as the last branch protection rule applies the branch protection rules for all the branches which do not fall into any of the mentioned branch protection rules.

For example if you have these branches - `users-1, users-2, releases-1, releases-2, temp-1, temp2, random`

then, branch protections like the below would set: 
`users-*` --> would cover `users-1, users-2` 
`releases-*` --> would cover `releases-1, releases-2`
`**\**` --> would cover everything else `temp-1, temp2, random`

Answer (score 0):

Protected branch rules use patterns from the [fnmatch syntax](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/File.html#method-c-fnmatch).

They don't work as RegExp expressions, so it's not possible to apply a lookahead expression to match only branches that not start with `private_`.

What you can do is to apply a prefix for protected branches. For example, all branches named `protected_` (or `public_`) would be the protected.

So you'd need the rule `protected_*`

Demo: https://repl.it/@herodrigues/LopsidedAwfulPortablesoftware